# Transparent background in custom overlay view not working

Tags: android

I am trying to recreate the Android PopupWindow or System AlertDialog look and feel where a view is floating on top of all Applications; I managed to show the view but not to display it with round transparent corners:

[image: The outer boarder should be not visible]
The box around the view should be not displayed.

The view layout

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="4dp"
    android:padding="4dp"
    app:elevation="8dp">

    <TextView
        android:background="@drawable/card_background"
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000"
        tools:text="Hallo" />

</FrameLayout>
```

The view background

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle">
    <stroke android:width="1px" android:color="#aaa"/>
    <corners android:radius="8dp"/>
    <solid android:color="#fff"/>

    <padding
        android:left="10dp"
        android:top="10dp"
        android:right="10dp"
        android:bottom="10dp" />
</shape>
```

And the view manager code:

```kotlin
        val wm = getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE) as WindowManager


        currentView.text.setText(text)
        currentView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE)

        val makeMeasureSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED)
        currentView.measure(makeMeasureSpec, makeMeasureSpec)
        currentView.layout(0, 0, currentView.measuredWidth, currentView.measuredHeight)

        val params = WindowManager.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_ACCESSIBILITY_OVERLAY,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE or WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT)

        params.gravity =  Gravity.START or Gravity.TOP
        params.x = location.left.toInt()
        params.y = location.bottom.toInt()

        if (!currentView.isAttachedToWindow) {
            wm.addView(currentView, params)
        } else {
            wm.updateViewLayout(currentView, params)
        }
```

I triedcouple of solutions related to other views like CardView without any success. So I suspect that the issue must be related to the WindowManager and its Window background drawable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a good night of sleep I found a solution for my Issue:

```
        // Set the background color of the top layer layout explicity
        currentView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)

        ...
        if (!currentView.isAttachedToWindow) {
            wm.addView(currentView, params)
        } else {
            wm.updateViewLayout(currentView, params)
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, you may want to change your `<solid>` color to something like `#50FFFFFF` where first 2 digit value means opacity value.

And also change your fragment background to your own background.

**card background**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle">
    <stroke android:width="1px" android:color="#aaa"/>
    <corners android:radius="8dp"/>
    <solid android:color="#50ffffff"/>

    <padding
        android:left="10dp"
        android:top="10dp"
        android:right="10dp"
        android:bottom="10dp" />
</shape>
```

**xml files**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="@drawable/card_background"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="4dp"
    android:padding="4dp"
    app:elevation="8dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000"
        tools:text="Hallo" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but that does not work. As you can see the boarder is drawn correctly, the outer "fill" is actually a graphical fragment of the drawing pipeline, but i am not sure why because the params of the addView call state that transluciant pixels are supported.